# Graph is not showing in AGE Viewer for Edges

Tags: database, postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I am connecting the instance of AGE running on WSL to AGE Viewer running on Window. It is working fine. When I run query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('university', $$
        MATCH (v)
        RETURN v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

It works fine and show all the nodes in the `university` Graph in both Table and Graph View. But when I run:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('university', $$
        MATCH ()-[e]->()
        RETURN e
$$) as (v agtype);
```

It shows result in only Table View and Graph View shows nothing. How can I solve this issue?

**Graph View:**
[image]

**Table View:**
[image]

Comment: AGE Viewer can't draw edges without its start node and end node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be resolved with the below code and to see the relationship in the graph view, a modification in query is needed to include the connected nodes. This is how to retrieve it:

```
 SELECT *
FROM cypher('university', $$
        MATCH (n1)-[e]->(n2)
        RETURN n1, e, n2
$$) as (n1 agtype, e agtype, n2 agtype);
```